# Delete multiple pages in Microsoft OneNote 2013

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

I've Googled this and for other versions than 2013 the answer seems to be the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click.

However, for me this only works in an open section (*backup file*) not in the standard regular Notebook.

When I delete a page I'm immediately thrown back to the first page in that section, so if the next page to be deleted is 112 it is a bit cumbersome to get back to that point and also to avoid selecting the wrong page and inadvertently delete the wrong page.

Answer (score 1):

What I've been doing is simply moving all of the files (from quick note for me) that I want to keep into a different folder and then deleting the quick notes tab! It was frustrating because I screenshot notes for school and have to "paste" them together into one page then delete hundreds after.
This works for me, just MAKE SURE that you have all the pages you don't want deleted in a different folder!!!!

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer, and you do not yet have the required reputation points to comment.